# Cross browser issue with script

Tags: javascript

I have written some JavaScript code as follows

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function(myEvent) {
  myEvent.returnValue = "Bye Bye Fool!...";
}

var txt = ['Y', 'o', 'u', ' ', 'a', 'r', 'e', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'f', 'o', 'o', 'l', '.', ' '];
var value = document.getElementById('txtinput').value;
var lastNum = 0;
document.getElementById('txtinput').onkeypress = function() {
  myFunction()
}
document.getElementById('txtinput').onkeyup = function() {
  myFunction2(event)
}

function myFunction() {
  for (i = lastNum; i <= lastNum; i++) {
    value = value + txt[i];
  }
  if (i < txt.length) {
    lastNum = i;
  } else {
    lastNum = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById('txtinput').value = value;
}

function myFunction2(event) {
  var x = event.keyCode;
  var y = String.fromCharCode(x);
  value = String(value, y);
  document.getElementById('txtinput').value = value;
}
```

```html
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" id='txtinput'></textarea>
```

I was nothing special but just for fun (actually I am a new programmer & trying to enhance my programming skills). It's working very well in Chrome, but in Firefox it has a issue. Here is the idea :

It will make a text area to type & when user will start typing it will only type "You are a fool." That it picks from array named 'txt'. So, once a key is pressed, it will print the letter and on releasing the key, it will remove the last printed letter (i.e. It will only show the letters from array & remove the pressed key letter).

Chrome is executing it very well but in Firefox, the `onkeyup` event is not working. It removes the pressed letter when next key is pressed.

Comment: While this isn't the source of the problem, the loop in myFunction will always run only once. Not sure what you were trying to do there.

Comment: Look at the Developer console for errors.

Comment: fiddle of above code https://jsfiddle.net/bmd7bLjv/

Comment: Yes Jacque, for loop will run only once each time so that when user presses a key, it will print only one letter a time.

Comment: Pardeep, please check check fiddle link on both Chrome & Firefox. In Chrome it's working well but in Firefox same problem occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no local `event` variable here:

```
document.getElementById('txtinput').onkeyup = function(){myFunction2(event)}
```

It appears Chrome may be passing a global `event` object that's working for you.

If you want the `keyup`'s event object to make it to your function, lose the wrapper:

```
document.getElementById('txtinput').onkeyup = myFunction2;
```

Comment: Sorry, but it wouldn't work. I want to detect the key that user has pressed, so I have passed global event. Any more suggestion please.

Comment: Ya got it. I had placed event in myFunction2 that is why it was not working. Thanks Paul....